# Best practice when deploying apps

Tags: .net, heroku, deployment

So, i have 3 apps (two backend in .net and one frontend in angular) and im wondering what are the best practices to deploy them. When i run them local(for development purposes), i have the url (one backend communicates with the other and the angular communicate with both of them) to 'localhost' however i need to change it every time i deploy the apps. Is there anyway to make this automatic so i don't need to change it manually everytime ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. "Best practice" questions are virtually all off-topic as too broad and primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

> Configure a static IP port number in configuration. Then the services
>   will open in same port number when we execute them.